# FlexSlider - nav images

Tags: css, image, flexslider

I am using FlexSlider for the first time can't get the nav images to display on my project. The url to the 'theme' folder is correct in the flexSlider css file. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

It was a url issue. It needed to be in parenthesis.